# MySql inserting decimals into table

Tags: mysql

I have:

```
create table a ( x decimal(4, 4) unsigned zerofill);
insert into a value(10);
select * from a
```

Outputs:

```
+--------+
| x      |
+--------+
| 0.9999 |
+--------+
```

Why not 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given 4 total places (in the first 4), and all 4 of them are allocated to the right of the decimal point (the second 4).

Try doing

```
create table a ( x decimal(6, 4) unsigned zerofill);
insert into a value(10);
select * from a
```